# passing DOTNET class object from one php page to another

Tags: php, .net, object

I am working on a project which communicates with cash register machines. That machine has own DLLs which were written on DOTNET. I am creating the project on PHP. Those DOTNET DLL's have some methods for communicating. And I am calling them on PHP. First of all I create an object of that class;

```
$abc = new DOTNET("FirstDotNet, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxx", "FirstDotNet.Class1");
```

Then I call the methods in the same page ;

```
$abc->ConnectToMachine();
$abc->SignInCashier();
$abc->SendPrintItem();
```

If I call those in the same page, there is no problem, it prints. But If I  call last method on a different page, it gives error, so doesnt print.

I dont want to call first two methods again and again in every page, because those methods take 30 seconds. It is a long time for everytime I want to print.

How can I pass the object that I created in the first page, to another page in order to continue using same object's methods on other pages.

Comment: Serialize it and store it somewhere (db, file, in memory)

Comment: ...or in `$_SESSION`

Comment: @u_mulder   Thank you for your reply. If I serialize that object, does it return a string value? And how can I store it in memory? When I unserialize it on other page, my connection that is created to other machine will be lost or not?

Comment: @Rob Gudgeon , I tried to store in $_SESSION["abc"] and use it on other page, but it makes my connection lost which I created with $abc object in the first page

Comment: are you calling session_start() on both pages?

Comment: @Rob Gudgeon Yes I am calling session_start() on both pages. I tried something like this in the second page, but it didnt work

    session_start();
    $xyz = new DOTNET("FirstDotNet, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxx", "FirstDotNet.Class1");
    $xyz = $_SESSION["abc"];
    echo $xyz->PrintItem();

Comment: Anybody knows how to pass my dotnet object to another page in order to continue using?

Answer (score 0):

Both pages will need to start a session; page 1 will create the object & store it in the session; page 2 will start the session & retrieve the object. Note I've never used DotNet stuff before, so I've no idea if DotNet objects can be stored in sessions, but I can't find anything that says they *can't*.

Page 1:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$obj = new DOTNET("FirstDotNet, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxx", "FirstDotNet.Class1");
$_SESSION['object'] = $obj;
?>
```

Page 2:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
echo $_SESSION['object']->PrintItem();
?>
```